# Parameter lost when calling a dll method using mozilla 1.8.1.18 on DMP

Tags: c#, dll, service, parameters, dmp

This is a problem that has occurred after a Cisco 4400 DMP upgrade to Mozilla 1.8.1.18 (firmware release 5.3.5).

A C# method uses a command line (QueryString) parameter to invoke a method in a DLL using this variable as a parameter.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public string Get_Channel_Orientation(int channelId)
{
    ChannelService channelService = new ChannelService();
    return channelService.GetRootOrientation(channelId);        
}
```

channelId is a QueryString parameter. This has functioned correctly until the browser upgrade.
Now, what happens is the channelId value is always null.  If you place a literal instead of the QueryString parameter such as:

```
  return channelService.GetRootOrientation(123);
```

it works correctly even with the upgraded browser.

And even though it is null when passed to the Service method, if you print out the value of channelId to the console, it is correct (i.e. it is the value passed in the URL)

The situation seems impossible because it is server-side, and should not be affected by the browser version, but there is no other difference I can see between working and non-working cases.

Comment: could you pass that in as int ref channelId or assign that to a Session Variable .. then return channelService.GetRootOrientation(session["channelId"]); can you show how the URL is currently being passed, meaning the value you have in the debugger..

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible to debug this using the device with a debugger as it is a closed Cisco box.  The only way debug is to print values to the console. I know that the code has the correct value -- for some reason it is not getting passed to the Service when it is a URL parameter.